# paper.js hide/show layer?

Tags: paperjs

I have a layer with a lot of Symbols, and I would like to hide and show that entire layer with all his elements.

to hide I do it with `myLayer.remove();` but to show it there is no methods...
On their tutorial they say `project.activeLayer.addChild(myObject);` but it doesn't seem to work with a layer. (http://paperjs.org/tutorials/project-items/project-hierarchy/)

If someone can help me or tell me if I need to do it differently ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call Layer.remove(), that Layer instance is removed from the project.layers array.  To re-show the removed layer (and any objects in it), push it back onto project.layers.

```
var blueSquare = Path.Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size (50, 50));
blueSquare.fillColor = 'blue';

var newLayer = new Layer();
newLayer.activate();    // so that redCircle will be added to newLayer
var redCircle = Path.Circle(new Point(100, 100), 50);
redCircle.fillColor = 'red';

newLayer.remove();      // this prevents the redCircle from being drawn
project.layers.push(newLayer);  // now the redCircle is back
```

Alternatively, instead of `newLayer.remove();` you can use `newLayer.visible = false;` or `newLayer.opacity = 0;` so that the newLayer is never actually removed from the project.layers array, although with those approaches selected Items still show wireframes even if the actual Items cannot be seen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I used the opacity = 0 method, cause that layer was below the others so it didn't bother.

Answer (score 2):

There is a property called as **visibility** for layers. you can set it either true/false.

```
paper.Layer.prototype.hide = function(){
   this.visibility = false
}

paper.Layer.prototype.show = function(){
   this.visibility = true
}
```

now when you create a new layer, You can call show or hide method on the object for changing the visibility.

```
baseLayer = new Layer()

// hiding layer
baseLayer.hide()

//showing layer
baseLayer.show()
```

> how ever this does not remove the layer from being the active layer.
>   whatever changes you make, will be in the active layer even if its
>   hidden.

For that i make one layer called. **rootLayer** and set it as active ( `rootLayer.activate()` ) when they are hidden. its a hack but it gets the job done